# How is Starlight Reflected by Mirrors?

Tags: optics, astronomy, stars

[image]

The chosen star is on the Z-axis of Mirror-A (Red). The Star image appears on the
face of this Mirror at the Origin of the CoSys.

Starlight Rays (Yellow lines) remain parallel, and do not diverge with distance.

Mirror-B (Green) has been rotated 45-degrees on its Y-axis and aligned edge-to-edge
with Mirror-A (Red).

Q1. Will an image of this Star appear on Mirror-B (Green)?

Q2. If so, where on the face of this Mirror will the Star image appear? And why there,
and not elsewhere?

---

EDIT:  This is NOT a "Homework Question." I am 70 years old and not in school or taking any classes. My question is germane to a *personal* project which requires calibration by sighting on a single star for navigation by Sextant. There are *no* mathematical calculations involved, hence no "answers" to an assigned question. The underlying principle involves a light source at a distance measured in light-years and how its reflection in a mirror differs from that of a nearby collimated light source. I have researched this problem for a considerable time and many resources without a satisfactory result.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE].  Apologies for the closure;  we have some users who (in my opinion) vote to close questions too readily. I have voted to re-open, but it might also be worth clarifying why you think the star wouldn't appear in the green mirror.

Comment: Also, the "image" of an object is not located in the plane of the mirror;  it's located behind the mirror, at the same distance as separates the object and the mirror.  [Reading up on this](https://openstax.org/books/college-physics-2e/pages/25-7-image-formation-by-mirrors) might help you answer your own question.

Comment: I responded to these questions at the time, but I /couldn't find them here. Perhaps they were blocked despite the re-opened status?

First, *thank you* Michael for the re-opening. It restores my faith in Stack. Of course I most definitely agree regarding "some users." You would think that *everyone* would prefer to attract members, not chase them away.

Q1. Will an image of this Star appear on Mirror-B (Green)?